# How to Convert Date to Quarterly revenue in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Order and Product.

Requirement is to represent table revenue in Quarterly colmns

```
ProductId   Q1          Q2          Q3          Q4
P1         30240         0          0            0
```

I am so confused to keep quarterly as cols. Any help is appreciated. Please see image for clear view

[image]

Comment: mysql <> Oracle , which one are you working on?

Comment: Have a look for conditional aggregation and post your query if you get into trouble.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I am a newbie in mysql. Still thinking about the approach. @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: Looking for a logic @KaushikNayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may have data across multiple years; so I have gone ahead and grouped the data by order year as well, using [`Year()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function.
- Use conditional aggregations functions like [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to sum a particular row based on a grouping of particular [`Quarter()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter).
- If you want to get sale values for all the product(s), you will need to do a `Left join` from `Product` table to the `Order` table, because there may be few product(s) in the `Product` table with no corresponding entry in the `Order` table at all.
- Also, `Order` is a [Reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O) in MySQL. You should change your table name to something else. In case you don't want to, you can use backticks (`) around it. And, it is a good practice to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/).

Try the following query (in MySQL):

```
SELECT YEAR(o.order_date) AS order_year, 
       p.ProductId, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 1, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q1, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 2, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q2, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 3, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q3, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 4, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q4 
FROM Product AS p 
LEFT JOIN `Order` AS o ON o.ProductId = p.ProductId 
GROUP BY order_year, p.ProductId
```

- In case, you want to consider only those product(s), where there has been some sale atleast. You can change the `Left Join` to `Inner Join`.
- Also, you can change the order of tables in the Join.

Try the following in this case (in MySQL):

```
SELECT YEAR(o.order_date) AS order_year, 
       p.ProductId, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 1, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q1, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 2, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q2, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 3, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q3, 
       SUM(IF(QUARTER(o.OrderDate) = 4, o.Quantity*p.Cost, 0)) AS Q4 
FROM `Order` AS o 
INNER JOIN Product AS p ON o.ProductId = p.ProductId 
GROUP BY order_year, p.ProductId
```

Comment: Your third point isn't strictly correct, it's to make sure that all products are in the output table regardless of whether there were any orders for that product *ever*

Comment: Thanks Madhur, your idea worked. Only thing is to append ")" at the end condition for sum